# Way to forward remote internal network ip and port to same ip and port on local mac

Tags: port-forwarding, mac, kafka

For development reasons I want to connect my local machine (macos) to a remote private network of a kafka/zookeeper cluster.

When I do port forwarding with

> ssh root@000.000.000.000 -N -L 10.0.0.8:9092:10.0.0.8:9092

my mac is not doing this (probably for security reasons) and states "Could not request local forwarding."

If I just put it on localhost:9029 the kafka-broker can't find the other nodes within the private network because of the broker meta data pointing to the private network.

I also thought about running a local haproxy on 10.0.0.8 and proxy tcp traffic to localhost on different ports, but no chance. It states "Cannot bind socket [10.0.0.8:9092]"

How could I get 10.0.0.8:9029 on my local machine pointing to a forwarded port on the remote?

Answer (score 0):

In linux, something like this could be achieved with iptables, I'm not sure about mac though. What you're really wanting to look into is something like [Network Address Translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation), or NAT. Another option is a proxy. NAT is likely your easiest route.

Could you provide more details on your network topology? Do you have control of the Kafka network?